# How to load the created form to XPages?

Tags: xpages

Can anyone help me figure out how to load/embed the created form to XPage using IBM Domino Designer? I already loaded the view to the `XPages`. I want to load the form somewhere in my footer panel.

[image: Image Reference]

Answer (score 7):

All you have to do is

1. Add a document data source to your xpage and specify in the data source which form to use
2. Use the "data" eclipse view and drag all the fields to your footer panel

Comment: Thanks! It's running running perfectly :)

Comment: nice to hear that it worked for you. If the answer solved your problem, please help the community by accepting the answer, thanks!

Comment: Thank you sir. How to accept this answer? Sorry I'm new to stackoverflow and I'm not able to vote due to not enough reputation :))

Comment: Hi Sir, I have another question about domino. Hoping for your answer again :) Thanks!